# Laravel does not want to auto-inject dependencies in Service Provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a service provider:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store;

use File;

use App\Models\Translation;

class ModuleTranslationsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $cache;

    public function __construct (Store $cache) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    /**
     * Load the config from the database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $translations = $this->cache->remember('translations', function() {
            //Load and return translations.
        });
        $this->app->singleton('translations', function($app) use ($translations) {
            return $translations;
        });
    }

}
```

However I get the following error when the app is run (artisan or browser):

```
ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  Argument 1 passed to App\Providers\ModuleTranslationsServiceProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store, instance of Illuminate\Foundation\Application given, called in /home/user/projects/AppPlatform/vendor/laravel/framework/  
  src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 150 and defined
```

Normally, Laravel auto-injects contracts via the constructor. Is this a limitation of Service Providers? Or am I doing it wrong?

**EDIT:**

I changed the code to reflect the advice from Iamzozo:

```
public function boot(Store $cache) {
    $this->cache = $cache;
}
```

But this only returned:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Call to a member function remember() on null
```

So I tried instantiating from the app:

```
$cache = $this->app['Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager'];
```

But this only returned:

```
[ReflectionException]       
Class cache does not exist
```

And trying to instantiate the contract:

```
$cache = $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store'];
```

gets me a:

```
[Illuminate\Container\BindingResolutionException]               
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Store] is not instantiable.
```

Last thing I know of: using the facade:

```
use Cache;
//...
$translations = Cache::remember( [...]
```

but this in turn returns:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::remember()
```

So I checked my providers array:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * ...
     */
    'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
    /*
     * ...
     */
    'App\Providers\ModuleTranslationsServiceProvider',
],
```

so the cache is loaded before my Service Provider.

I have no new ideas at this point.

The php version is 5.6.14 running on PHP-FPM through Apache. The Laravel version is 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I wasn't clear with my answer, so I updated the whole, this solution works on Laravel 5.1:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager as Cache;

use File;

use App\Models\Translation;

class ModuleTranslationsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Load the config from the database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Update for redis:
        $this->app->register(\Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);

        $cache = new Cache($this->app);
        $translations = $cache->remember('translations', function() {
            //Load and return translations.
        });
        $this->app->singleton('translations', function($app) use ($translations) {
            return $translations;
        });
    }
}
```

I didn't realized, that `Cache\Store` what you tried to use is an interface.

Comment: 1. Don't create an empty constructor. 2. Don't set it as an instance property; pass around the `$cache` instance to whomever needs it.

Comment: 1. Yep, empty constructor is not needed, just show not to put there. (updated)  2. Any other solution?

Comment: Your first idea gives me `Call to a member function remember() on null`. The second one gives `[ReflectionException] Class cache does not exist`

Comment: I wrote it a bit difficult, and also wrote solutions what I tried, and did not work, but maybe I wasn't clear about that. Updated the answer, and simplified it. That's what you tried?

Comment: Yes, but now it says : `[ReflectionException] Class redis does not exist`

Comment: I've tested with file cache driver. Is Cache works outside of your service provider, like in your controller?

Comment: Update the answer for redis, added this line: `$this->app->register(\Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);`

Comment: You got me on the right track. I kept on getting more errors, until I commented out the register function and ran `php artisan clear-compiled`.